# How to indicate if UTXO is already spent, without examining the entire blockchain?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

Let's suppose I want to check if someone has **UTXOs** in some **blockchain**. This person can send me addresses of all **transactions** which contain his **UTXOs**. But I need to determine that all these **UTXOs** are not spent yet. For this, I should examine the entire **blockchain** starting from first user's **UTXO**. Is there any way to implement **UTXO** pool not to examine the blockchain any time I need to validate someone's transaction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about [blockchain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

In Bitcoin-core, if you sync your node once (which will take some time), afterwards, you don't need to use the entire blockchain in order to validate UTXO. This is because a separate database is kept of just the UTXO. That makes UTXO validation more efficient since it only needs to search through about 1/10 of the amount of data.

If you don't validate them in the first place (by syncing the node), you can't be sure the transaction is valid, because you wouldn't know if it's ancestors were valid. By keeping a dedicated UTXO set the node does the validation once for the whole blockchain, but afterwards, it can just update the UTXO set by deleting spent UTXO and saving new UTXO.